# Define cover colors based on current month

Tags: macros, color, datetime

I am writing a style guide documentation and I want to make visually appealing what the document was updated using the cover color.

The main idea is to automatically update cover color based on the month when the document was compiled.

The cover colors are defined as `coverBackground` and `coverFont`.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{grayOne}{rgb}{0.95, 0.95, 0.96}

\definecolor{coverBackground}{rgb}{0.952, 0.929, 0.858}
\definecolor{coverFont}{rgb}{0.223, 0.239, 0.313}

\usepackage[backgroundcolor=grayOne,linecolor=white]{mdframed}

\begin{document}

    \begin{titlepage}
        \begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=coverBackground]
            \centering
            \vspace*{.25\textheight}
            \textcolor{coverFont}{\Huge Page title}\\
            \vspace{10pt}\par
            \textcolor{coverFont}{\today}\\
            \vspace*{.25\textheight}
        \end{mdframed}
    \end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

I also have a utility file where I have defined a large set of colors it would be great to use them.

```latex
    %--------------------------------------------
    %   Open Color Palette
    %   https://yeun.github.io/open-color/
    %--------------------------------------------
    % GRAY
    \definecolor{grayZero}{rgb}{0.97, 0.98, 0.98}
    \definecolor{grayOne}{rgb}{0.95, 0.95, 0.96}
    \definecolor{grayTwo}{rgb}{0.91, 0.93, 0.94}
    \definecolor{grayThree}{rgb}{0.87, 0.89, 0.9}
    \definecolor{grayFour}{rgb}{0.81, 0.83, 0.85}
    \definecolor{grayFive}{rgb}{0.68, 0.71, 0.74}
    \definecolor{graySix}{rgb}{0.53, 0.56, 0.59}
    \definecolor{graySeven}{rgb}{0.29, 0.31, 0.34}
    \definecolor{grayEight}{rgb}{0.2, 0.23, 0.25}
    \definecolor{grayNine}{rgb}{0.13, 0.15, 0.16}

    % RED
    \definecolor{redZero}{rgb}{1.0, 0.96, 0.96}
    \definecolor{redOne}{rgb}{1.0, 0.89, 0.89}
    \definecolor{redTwo}{rgb}{1.0, 0.79, 0.79}
    \definecolor{redThree}{rgb}{1.0, 0.66, 0.66}
    \definecolor{redFour}{rgb}{1.0, 0.53, 0.53}
    \definecolor{redFive}{rgb}{1.0, 0.42, 0.42}
    \definecolor{redSix}{rgb}{0.98, 0.32, 0.32}
    \definecolor{redSeven}{rgb}{0.94, 0.24, 0.24}
    \definecolor{redEight}{rgb}{0.88, 0.19, 0.19}
    \definecolor{redNine}{rgb}{0.79, 0.16, 0.16}

    % PINK
    \definecolor{pinkZero}{rgb}{1.0, 0.94, 0.96}
    \definecolor{pinkOne}{rgb}{1.0, 0.87, 0.92}
    \definecolor{pinkTwo}{rgb}{0.99, 0.76, 0.84}
    \definecolor{pinkThree}{rgb}{0.98, 0.64, 0.76}
    \definecolor{pinkFour}{rgb}{0.97, 0.51, 0.67}
    \definecolor{pinkFive}{rgb}{0.94, 0.4, 0.58}
    \definecolor{pinkSix}{rgb}{0.9, 0.29, 0.5}
    \definecolor{pinkSeven}{rgb}{0.84, 0.2, 0.42}
    \definecolor{pinkEight}{rgb}{0.76, 0.15, 0.36}
    \definecolor{pinkNine}{rgb}{0.65, 0.12, 0.3}

    % GRAPE
    \definecolor{grapeZero}{rgb}{0.97, 0.94, 0.99}
    \definecolor{grapeOne}{rgb}{0.95, 0.85, 0.98}
    \definecolor{grapeTwo}{rgb}{0.93, 0.75, 0.98}
    \definecolor{grapeThree}{rgb}{0.9, 0.6, 0.97}
    \definecolor{grapeFour}{rgb}{0.85, 0.47, 0.95}
    \definecolor{grapeFive}{rgb}{0.8, 0.36, 0.91}
    \definecolor{grapeSix}{rgb}{0.75, 0.29, 0.86}
    \definecolor{grapeSeven}{rgb}{0.68, 0.24, 0.79}
    \definecolor{grapeEight}{rgb}{0.61, 0.21, 0.71}
    \definecolor{grapeNine}{rgb}{0.53, 0.18, 0.61}

    % VIOLET
    \definecolor{violetZero}{rgb}{0.95, 0.94, 1.0}
    \definecolor{violetOne}{rgb}{0.9, 0.86, 1.0}
    \definecolor{violetTwo}{rgb}{0.82, 0.75, 1.0}
    \definecolor{violetThree}{rgb}{0.69, 0.59, 0.99}
    \definecolor{violetFour}{rgb}{0.59, 0.46, 0.98}
    \definecolor{violetFive}{rgb}{0.52, 0.37, 0.97}
    \definecolor{violetSix}{rgb}{0.47, 0.31, 0.95}
    \definecolor{violetSeven}{rgb}{0.44, 0.28, 0.91}
    \definecolor{violetEight}{rgb}{0.4, 0.25, 0.85}
    \definecolor{violetNine}{rgb}{0.37, 0.24, 0.77}

    % INDIGO
    \definecolor{indigoZero}{rgb}{0.93, 0.95, 1.0}
    \definecolor{indigoOne}{rgb}{0.86, 0.89, 1.0}
    \definecolor{indigoTwo}{rgb}{0.73, 0.78, 1.0}
    \definecolor{indigoThree}{rgb}{0.57, 0.65, 1.0}
    \definecolor{indigoFour}{rgb}{0.45, 0.56, 0.99}
    \definecolor{indigoFive}{rgb}{0.36, 0.49, 0.98}
    \definecolor{indigoSix}{rgb}{0.3, 0.43, 0.96}
    \definecolor{indigoSeven}{rgb}{0.26, 0.39, 0.92}
    \definecolor{indigoEight}{rgb}{0.23, 0.36, 0.86}
    \definecolor{indigoNine}{rgb}{0.21, 0.31, 0.78}

    % CYAN
    \definecolor{cyanZero}{rgb}{0.89, 0.98, 0.99}
    \definecolor{cyanOne}{rgb}{0.77, 0.96, 0.98}
    \definecolor{cyanTwo}{rgb}{0.6, 0.91, 0.95}
    \definecolor{cyanThree}{rgb}{0.4, 0.85, 0.91}
    \definecolor{cyanFour}{rgb}{0.23, 0.79, 0.86}
    \definecolor{cyanFive}{rgb}{0.13, 0.72, 0.81}
    \definecolor{cyanSix}{rgb}{0.08, 0.67, 0.75}
    \definecolor{cyanSeven}{rgb}{0.06, 0.6, 0.68}
    \definecolor{cyanEight}{rgb}{0.05, 0.52, 0.6}
    \definecolor{cyanNine}{rgb}{0.04, 0.45, 0.52}

    % BLUE
    \definecolor{blueZero}{rgb}{0.91, 0.96, 1.0}
    \definecolor{blueOne}{rgb}{0.82, 0.92, 1.0}
    \definecolor{blueTwo}{rgb}{0.65, 0.85, 1.0}
    \definecolor{blueThree}{rgb}{0.45, 0.75, 0.99}
    \definecolor{blueFour}{rgb}{0.3, 0.67, 0.97}
    \definecolor{blueFive}{rgb}{0.2, 0.6, 0.94}
    \definecolor{blueSix}{rgb}{0.13, 0.55, 0.9}
    \definecolor{blueSeven}{rgb}{0.11, 0.49, 0.84}
    \definecolor{blueEight}{rgb}{0.1, 0.44, 0.76}
    \definecolor{blueNine}{rgb}{0.09, 0.39, 0.67}

    % TEAL
    \definecolor{tealZero}{rgb}{0.9, 0.99, 0.96}
    \definecolor{tealOne}{rgb}{0.76, 0.98, 0.91}
    \definecolor{tealTwo}{rgb}{0.59, 0.95, 0.84}
    \definecolor{tealThree}{rgb}{0.39, 0.9, 0.75}
    \definecolor{tealFour}{rgb}{0.22, 0.85, 0.66}
    \definecolor{tealFive}{rgb}{0.13, 0.79, 0.59}
    \definecolor{tealSix}{rgb}{0.07, 0.72, 0.53}
    \definecolor{tealSeven}{rgb}{0.05, 0.65, 0.47}
    \definecolor{tealEight}{rgb}{0.04, 0.57, 0.41}
    \definecolor{tealNine}{rgb}{0.03, 0.5, 0.36}

    % GREEN
    \definecolor{greenZero}{rgb}{0.92, 0.98, 0.93}
    \definecolor{greenOne}{rgb}{0.83, 0.98, 0.85}
    \definecolor{greenTwo}{rgb}{0.7, 0.95, 0.73}
    \definecolor{greenThree}{rgb}{0.55, 0.91, 0.6}
    \definecolor{greenFour}{rgb}{0.41, 0.86, 0.49}
    \definecolor{greenFive}{rgb}{0.32, 0.81, 0.4}
    \definecolor{greenSix}{rgb}{0.25, 0.75, 0.34}
    \definecolor{greenSeven}{rgb}{0.22, 0.7, 0.3}
    \definecolor{greenEight}{rgb}{0.18, 0.62, 0.27}
    \definecolor{greenNine}{rgb}{0.17, 0.54, 0.24}

    % LIME
    \definecolor{limeZero}{rgb}{0.96, 0.99, 0.89}
    \definecolor{limeOne}{rgb}{0.91, 0.98, 0.78}
    \definecolor{limeTwo}{rgb}{0.85, 0.96, 0.64}
    \definecolor{limeThree}{rgb}{0.75, 0.92, 0.46}
    \definecolor{limeFour}{rgb}{0.66, 0.89, 0.29}
    \definecolor{limeFive}{rgb}{0.58, 0.85, 0.18}
    \definecolor{limeSix}{rgb}{0.51, 0.79, 0.12}
    \definecolor{limeSeven}{rgb}{0.45, 0.72, 0.09}
    \definecolor{limeEight}{rgb}{0.4, 0.66, 0.06}
    \definecolor{limeNine}{rgb}{0.36, 0.58, 0.05}

    % YELLOW
    \definecolor{yellowZero}{rgb}{1.0, 0.98, 0.86}
    \definecolor{yellowOne}{rgb}{1.0, 0.95, 0.75}
    \definecolor{yellowTwo}{rgb}{1.0, 0.93, 0.6}
    \definecolor{yellowThree}{rgb}{1.0, 0.88, 0.4}
    \definecolor{yellowFour}{rgb}{1.0, 0.83, 0.23}
    \definecolor{yellowFive}{rgb}{0.99, 0.77, 0.1}
    \definecolor{yellowSix}{rgb}{0.98, 0.69, 0.02}
    \definecolor{yellowSeven}{rgb}{0.96, 0.62, 0.0}
    \definecolor{yellowEight}{rgb}{0.94, 0.55, 0.0}
    \definecolor{yellowNine}{rgb}{0.9, 0.47, 0.0}

    % ORANGE
    \definecolor{orangeZero}{rgb}{1.0, 0.96, 0.9}
    \definecolor{orangeOne}{rgb}{1.0, 0.91, 0.8}
    \definecolor{orangeTwo}{rgb}{1.0, 0.85, 0.66}
    \definecolor{orangeThree}{rgb}{1.0, 0.75, 0.47}
    \definecolor{orangeFour}{rgb}{1.0, 0.66, 0.3}
    \definecolor{orangeFive}{rgb}{1.0, 0.57, 0.17}
    \definecolor{orangeSix}{rgb}{0.99, 0.49, 0.08}
    \definecolor{orangeSeven}{rgb}{0.97, 0.4, 0.03}
    \definecolor{orangeEight}{rgb}{0.91, 0.35, 0.05}
    \definecolor{orangeNine}{rgb}{0.85, 0.28, 0.06}
```

Comment: Also is appropriate to have somethink like this: If January then \definecolor{coverBackground}{rgb}{0.83, 0.98, 0.85} ....

Comment: Your reputation points are now high enough you are allowed to vote up helpful answers. Please consider to do this with the answers below. It is the way to say "Thank You" here ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use command `\ifcase\month` to define the different colors like:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}


\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{grayOne}{rgb}{0.95, 0.95, 0.96}

\definecolor{coverBackground}{rgb}{0.952, 0.929, 0.858}
\definecolor{coverFont}{rgb}{0.223, 0.239, 0.313}

\usepackage[backgroundcolor=grayOne,linecolor=white]{mdframed}

\begin{document}

% define coverBackground and coverFont
  \ifcase\month\relax
%   \ValueWasZero
  \or % Jan
    \definecolor{coverBackground}{rgb}{0.952, 0.929, 0.858}
    \definecolor{coverFont}{rgb}{0.223, 0.239, 0.313}
  \or % feb
    \colorlet{coverBackground}{gray}
    \colorlet{coverFont}{red}
  \or % mar
    \colorlet{coverBackground}{blue}
    \colorlet{coverFont}{yellow}
  \or % Apr
    \colorlet{coverBackground}{red}
    \colorlet{coverFont}{green}
  \or % Mai
    \colorlet{coverBackground}{pink}
    \colorlet{coverFont}{black}
  \or % Jun
    \colorlet{coverBackground}{red}
    \colorlet{coverFont}{green}
  \or % Jul
    \definecolor{coverBackground}{rgb}{0.952, 0.929, 0.858}
    \definecolor{coverFont}{rgb}{0.223, 0.239, 0.313}
  \or % aug
    \colorlet{coverBackground}{red}
    \colorlet{coverFont}{green}
  \or % sep
    \colorlet{coverBackground}{red}
    \colorlet{coverFont}{green}
  \or % oct
    \colorlet{coverBackground}{red}
    \colorlet{coverFont}{green}
  \or % nov
    \colorlet{coverBackground}{red}
    \colorlet{coverFont}{green}
  \or % dec
    \colorlet{coverBackground}{red}
    \colorlet{coverFont}{green}
  \else % error
    \colorlet{coverBackground}{red}
    \colorlet{coverFont}{green}
  \fi


\begin{titlepage}
  \begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=coverBackground]
    \centering
    \vspace*{.25\textheight}
    \textcolor{coverFont}{\Huge Page title}\\
    \vspace{10pt}\par
    \textcolor{coverFont}{\today}\\
    \vspace*{.25\textheight}
  \end{mdframed}
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

I showed both methods, defining color directly with `\definecolor{coverFont}` or using your other predefined colors with `\colorlet{coverFont}`. I used standard colors to show the principal way, please change that to the colors you need. The last `\else` is only to have an regular exit if a month is not recognized (should not happen, bur sure is sure ...).

With the given MWE you get the result:

[image: resulting titlepage]

Okay, sorry, I know the color hurts ... But for an example ...

Answer (score 0):

For implementing a forking-mechanism you can have LaTeX evaluate the integer-parameter `\month`.

The forking-mechanism can be based on `\ifcase`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

The date of compilation is: \today

\ifcase\month This should never be done.% <- case month = 0
\or This is done in January.% <- case month = 1
\or This is done in February.% <- case month = 2
\or This is done in March.% <- case month = 3
\or This is done in April.% <- case month = 4
\or This is done in May.% <- case month = 5
\or This is done in June.% <- case month = 6
\or This is done in July.% <- case month = 7
\or This is done in August.% <- case month = 8
\or This is done in September.% <- case month = 9
\or This is done in October.% <- case month = 10
\or This is done in November.% <- case month = 11
\or This is done in December.% <- case month = 12
\fi

\end{document}
```

You can also use something like my `\KeepKthOfLArguments`-macro:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
%% Code for \KeepKthOfLArguments: 
%%=============================================================================
%% Paraphernalia:
%% \UD@firstoftwo, \UD@secondoftwo, \UD@PassFirstToSecond, \UD@CheckWhetherNull
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\newcommand\UD@PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}%
  \UD@secondoftwo}{\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%=============================================================================
%% Keep only the K-th of L consecutive undelimited arguments.
%%   ( IF K < 1 OR K > L just remove L consecutive undelimited arguments. )
%%=============================================================================
%% \KeepKthOfLArguments{<integer number K>}%
%%                     {<integer number L>}%
%%                     <sequence of L consecutive undelimited arguments>
%%
%% If L < 1 yields nothing.
%% Else:
%%   If K >= 1 and K < L  yields:
%%     <K-th undelimited argument from <sequence of L consecutive undelimited 
%%      arguments>>
%%   If K < 1 or K > L
%%     (-> there is no K-th argument in the
%%         <sequence of L consecutive undelimited arguments> )
%%   yields nothing  but removal of <sequence of L consecutive 
%%          undelimited arguments>
\newcommand\KeepKthOfLArguments[2]{%
  \romannumeral0%
  % #1: <integer number K>
  % #2: <integer number L>
  \expandafter\UD@KeepKthOfLArgumentsKSmallerOneFork
  \expandafter{\romannumeral\number\number#1 000\expandafter}%
  \expandafter{\romannumeral\number\number#2 000}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand\UD@KeepKthOfLArgumentsKSmallerOneFork[2]{%
  % #1: <K letters m>
  % #2: <L letters m >
  \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}{% K is smaller than one:
    \UD@KeepKthOfLArgumentsRemoveNArguments{#2}{ }{}%
  }{% K is not smaller than one:
    \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond
    \expandafter{%
      \UD@firstoftwo{}#1%
    }{%
      \UD@KeepKthOfLArgumentsEvaluateLMinusKDifferenceLoop{#1}{#2}%
    }{#2}%
  }%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand\UD@KeepKthOfLArgumentsEvaluateLMinusKDifferenceLoop[4]{%
  % #1: <K letters m>  
  % #2: <L letters m>
  % (For detecting whether K>L or K<=L, during the loop letters m will
  %  be removed both from #1 and #2 until at least one of these arguments 
  %  is empty.
  %  When the loop terminates with 0<K<=L, #1 will be empty and #2
  %  will hold an amount of letters m corresponding to the the 
  %  difference L-K.
  %  When the loop terminates with K>L, #1 will not be empty and #2
  %  will be empty.
  % )
  % #3: <K-1 letters m>
  % #4: <L letters m>
  % (#3 and #4 will be left untouched during the loop so they can be 
  %  used for performing appropriate action when loop terminates as
  %  it is known whether K>L.)
  \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}{% We have K<=L:
     \UD@KeepKthOfLArgumentsRemoveNArguments{%
       #3%
      }{%
       \UD@KeepKthOfLArgumentsRemoveNArguments{#2}{ }%
      }{}%
  }{%
    \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#2}{% We have K>L:
      \UD@KeepKthOfLArgumentsRemoveNArguments{#4}{ }{}%
    }{% We don't know yet whether K<=L or K>L, thus remove letters m and 
      % do another iteration:
      \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond
      \expandafter{%
        \UD@firstoftwo{}#2%
      }{%
        \expandafter\UD@KeepKthOfLArgumentsEvaluateLMinusKDifferenceLoop
        \expandafter{%
          \UD@firstoftwo{}#1%
        }%
      }{#3}{#4}%
    }%
  }%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% \UD@KeepKthOfLArgumentsRemoveNArguments{<N letters m>}%
%%                                        {<argument 1>}%
%%                                        {<argument 2>}%
%%                                        <sequence of consecutive 
%%                                         undelimited arguments>
%%.............................................................................
%% Removes the first N undelimited arguments from the <sequence of 
%% consecutive undelimited arguments>, then inserts  
%% <argument 1><argument 2>
%%
%% On the one hand when providing <argument 2> empty, you can use 
%% <argument 1> for nesting calls to \UD@KeepKthOfLArgumentsRemoveNArguments.
%% On the other hand you can provide a <space token> for stopping
%% \romannumeral-expansion as  <argument 1> and have the
%% macro grab the <K-th undelimited argument> from the <sequence of L 
%% consecutive undelimited arguments> as <argument 2>.
%%
\newcommand\UD@KeepKthOfLArgumentsRemoveNArguments[3]{%
  %% #1: <N letters m>  
  %% #2: <Argument 1>   
  %% #3: <Argument 2>
  \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}{#2#3}{%
    \UD@firstoftwo{%
      \expandafter\UD@KeepKthOfLArgumentsRemoveNArguments
      \expandafter{%
        \UD@firstoftwo{}#1%
      }{#2}{#3}%
    }%
  }%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% End of code for \KeepKthOfLArguments.
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\makeatother

\newcommand\Monthfork{%
  \KeepKthOfLArguments{\month}{12}%
}%

\begin{document}

The date of compilation is: \today

\Monthfork{%
  This is done in January.%
}{%
  This is done in February.%
}{%
  This is done in March.%
}{%
  This is done in April.%
}{%
  This is done in May.%
}{%
  This is done in June.%
}{%
  This is done in July.%
}{%
  This is done in August.%
}{%
  This is done in September.%
}{%
  This is done in October.%
}{%
  This is done in November.%
}{%
  This is done in December.%
}%

\end{document}
```

[image]